# population structure by memory address in C

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

i am having a problem while populating the structure members with address reference but when it is done using the member it self then its fine.

with structure memmber

```
memcpy(&(AVPFieldStructureObj->resource_value),data_start,actual_data_length);
```

With Memory Address

```
memcpy((&AVPFieldStructureObj+fieldOffset),data_start,actual_data_length);
```

where actual_data_length is the size of varibale and data_start is pointer pointing to the data buffer.

with memory its giving garbage value when i print the field and after executing the whole i am getting a segmentation fault but when debug with GDB the program exited normally.there was no segmentation fault

please suggest

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Soheb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `fieldOffset` is the offset in bytes?

If you're doing something like:

```
Type* pointer = somewhere;
pointer += 3;
```

then `pointer` gets moved forward by `3*sizeof(Type)` bytes - so 3 `Type` objects forward.

So in your code, in the latter variant, you're not offsetting the address by `fieldOffset` bytes, but by `fieldOffset*sizeof(AVPFieldStructureObj)` bytes.

You can work around that by casting to the pointer to `char*` temporarily.

Comment: Thanks Kos,it works, extremely sorry that i missed this logic or concept,its working fine now.....                                                 so the correct syntax is               memcpy(((char*)AVPFieldStructureObj+fieldOffset),data_start,actual_data_length);

Comment: c99 supports the offsetof() macro in stddef.h  You may want to try it your code.